# Attaching my email and BTC address to my eos account

Tags: accounts, account-name

Is there a way to attach my email address and bitcoin address to my eos account name? And also be able to query this data from a block explorer? Basically looking for a way to set a property value to an account name. Is this even doable without using IPFS to store this string data?

Comment: Yes this is doable for that you can use Demux .

Comment: will you add some bit of code to understand this easily? @NirdeshKumarChoudhary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want, you can create a smart contract to do this, which would be very much similar to the `regproxyinfo` contract (https://bloks.io/account/regproxyinfo). In this case, any user may send action to the smart contract with desired metadata, and the metadata will be saved into a multi-index table. When you want to query, just query the multi-index table as you want. Like: https://bloks.io/vote/proxies .

Answer (score 0):

1. Sign a message "This is my BTC address: xxxxx" using your EOS private key
2. Publish the signed message somewhere off-chain, you do not need to pollute blockchain itself with metadata

Comment: What if I wanted to pollute the blockchain with this meta data? How can this be done? How are people sending me messages currently?

Comment: There is no standard metadata for addresses on any blockchain, as far as I know. You are free to come up with any system. like an EOS dApp and smart contract that maintains EOS account -> Bitcoin address mappings for all users. Then you need to make this dApp popular for your use case and the problem is solved.